# Adwords Java integration

Tags: java, google-ads-api

I'm looking to write a Java app with a small section devote to ads (to support the operation.)

Unfortunately, my google-fu is finding nothing but Google's API for --managing adwords accounts-- in Java. I don't want to manage my adwords account with Java. I want to make adwords ads show up in my Java app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdWords is what you use when you want to create and run your own ads (and pay money).

AdSense is what you use when you want to display ads in your property (and get money for displaying them).

AdSense does not have a desktop product, though; all of the products are targeted at online usage and mobile apps, not desktop apps: https://www.google.com/adsense/static/en/Publishertools.html

Comment: How would integrating into a mobile app be different than into a desktop app? Also, it's an online application - I simply don't want to be confined to the browser - was planning to use web-start to pop out the app.

Comment: If you're looking to build an Android app, you might want to look at Google's AdMob: http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/

Comment: Nope, it's for a web-app, either Applet or java web start (undecided at this point.)

Comment: In that case, your options are rather limited, I'm afraid. Google's advertising programs focus on web pages and mobile phone apps, and what you're describing seems to be neither of them :-/

Answer (score 0):

*AFAIU* Google does not offer the chance to embed ads directly into an application.  It must be in a web page they can index and analyze (to help determine the best ad content for the page viewers).

---

As an aside, if you want to get your pages indexed fast by Google, throw some Google ads into them.  ;)